# Trying to get multiple input from user. Int + Str

Tags: python, string, input, integer

Im new to coding in python, and is trying to make this work.

if input from user is "name age" it works just fine. But I want it to work if user inputs either (name+age) or (name+lastname+age). If I input 3 values I get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

and if add      **name, lastname, age, =map(str, sys.stdin.readline().split())**    to the code. I get a not enough values error when user input name+lastname+age

Hopefully someone can help me :)

```
name, age, =map(str, sys.stdin.readline().split())
age = int(age)

if "Paul" in (name):

    result1 = (age*2)
    print("Answer is", + result1)
```

Comment: >>> name, lastname, age = map(str, sys.stdin.readline().split())
Name Lastname age 
>>> name
'Name'
>>> lastname
'Lastname'
>>> age
'age' It works if you don't have spaces in the name/lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to unpack the result of `split()` into two variables, you can use `join()` combined with list slicing to join everything but the last value into one (the `name`):

```
user = input().split()
age = int(user[-1])
name = ' '.join(user[:-1])

if "Paul" in name:
    print(f"Answer is {age*2}")
```

This works regardless of how many "words" are in the name:

```
Paul McCartney 42
Answer is 84
```

```
Pauline 42
Answer is 84
```

```
Paul W. S. Anderson 42
Answer is 84
```

Comment: This is excatly what i was looking for! Simple and easy to understand for me :D Thanks!

Comment: Note also that if you only care about the first name, you don't even need `join`; just set `name, age = user[0], int(user[-1])` to get the first and last list elements and ignore anything that might be in the middle.  Easy!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility - read the input line without the map, parse it, and then differentiate the input based on the number of elements in the resulting list,

```
import sys

entry = sys.stdin.readline()
entry = entry.strip().split()

if len(entry) == 2:
    # Name + age
    name = entry[0]
    age = int(entry[1])
    print(name, age)
elif len(entry) == 3:
    # Name + last name + age 
    name = entry[0]
    last_name = entry[1]
    age = int(entry[2])
    print(name, last_name, age)
else:
    raise ValueError('Wrong input arguments')

if "Paul" in (name):
    result1 = (age*2)
    print("Answer is", + result1)
```

If the input is nothing of the expected, this code raises an exception. You can instead keep prompting the user until they enter the right values. If you decide to keep the exception approach, consider using a more informative exception message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split something into a dynamic number of variables this way.

Instead you need to capture the input and then work out how many fields were passed in. Something like:

```
user = map(str, sys.stdin.readline().split())
lastname = ''
name = user[0]
age = user[1]
if len(user) == 3:
    lastname = user[1]
    age = user[2]
```

Comment: `age = user[1]` should probably be in another `if` or `else` branch. `map(str, ...)` is not necessary, as `sys.stdin.readline().split()` is already a list of strings. It's even harmful as the result of `map` is not a list and `[0]`, etc., can't be used with it.